# How to create list of pages and navigate to difference page at once

Tags: list, flutter, navigation

Here I have a list of id and title,
I would like to create pages. each page contains one sentences of title. Once click ok button it will navigate to next page of the list.
How can I do that within a single page?
I am a newbie but I would like to minimize my code,
it is a bit confusing.

Here are the images of my code.

[image]

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:starbucks/appLayout.dart';
import 'package:starbucks/appTheme.dart';
import 'package:starbucks/components/customAppBar.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:starbucks/pages/payment.dart';
import 'package:starbucks/providers/cartProvider.dart';
import 'package:starbucks/utils/data.dart';

class CartConfirm extends StatelessWidget {
  const CartConfirm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final totalPrice = context.read<CartProvider>().totalPrice;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppbar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              width: 1024,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: AppTheme.green),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "ราคารวม:       " ,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  AppLayout.staticField(content: " $totalPrice    "),
                  Text(
                    "        บาท",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 1024,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  AppLayout.button(title: "จ่ายด้วยบัตร", onPressed: () {}),
                  AppLayout.button(title: "จ่ายด้วยเงินสด", onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            Payment(id: id, title: title,),
                      ));},),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
  static List<Payment> payment = [
    Payment(
      id: 1,
      title: "กรุณาใส่เงิน",
    ),
    Payment(
      id: 2,
      title: "ระบบกำลังตรวจนับเงิน",
    ),
    Payment(
      id: 3,
      title: "กรุณารับบัตรคิวและเงินทอน",
    ),
    Payment(
      id: 4,
      title: "ขอบคุณที่ใช้บริการ",
    ),
  ];
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the codes that you have shared via the images.

Comment: Done. It's you again. Thank you :)